# Add Azure AD users to specific Security group (exception handling)

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I want to add users with a specific extensionAttribute to a security group. So far so good and the script is working for that. But unfortunately I get errors if a member is already part of the destination group.

Any ideas how I can avoid this?

```
Connect-AzureAD
$groupid = Get-AzureADGroup | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "SG specific"}
$groupids = $groupid.ObjectId

$useradd = Get-AzureADUser -All $true|select UserPrincipalName, ObjectId -ExpandProperty ExtensionProperty|Where {$_.extension_f6a32888337d4bff9fe8b5c93309a294_extensionAttribute15 -eq "C"}
$users = $useradd.ObjectId

foreach($user in $users){
    foreach($groupid in $groupids){
        Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $groupid -RefObjectId $user}
    }
}
```

UPDATE - New code:

```
Connect-AzureAD
$groupid = Get-AzureADGroup | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "SG Office365 Video*"}
$useradd = Get-AzureADUser -All $true|select UserPrincipalName, ObjectId -ExpandProperty ExtensionProperty|Where {$_.extension_f6a32888337d4bff9fe8b5c93309a294_extensionAttribute14 -eq "JP"}
$users = $useradd.ObjectId
$groupids = $groupid.ObjectId

# write-output "vor Schleife"


foreach($user in $users){

    foreach($groupid in $groupids){

        #Please pay attention to this part which you need to add it to your "foreach" loop.
        $Groups = New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.GroupIdsForMembershipCheck
        $Groups.GroupIds = $groupids

        $isExistInGroup = Select-AzureADGroupIdsUserIsMemberOf -ObjectId $user -GroupIdsForMembershipCheck $Groups

        $benutzer=Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $user

        if($isExistInGroup -eq $groupid){
            Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $groupid -RefObjectId $user
            write-host "Hinzugefügt: "$benutzer.DisplayName
        }else {
            write-host "Bereits vorhanden: "$benutzer.DisplayName
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can determine if the user in the group first in your powershell and then do the `Add-AzureADGroupMember` operation. Please refer to my command below:

```
Connect-AzureAD

foreach($user in $users){
    foreach($groupid in $groupids){

        #Please pay attention to this part which you need to add it to your "foreach" loop.
        $Groups = New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.GroupIdsForMembershipCheck
        $Groups.GroupIds = $groupid

        $isExistInGroup = Select-AzureADGroupIdsUserIsMemberOf  -ObjectId $user -GroupIdsForMembershipCheck $Groups

        if($isExistInGroup -eq $groupid){
          #don't do "Add-AzureADGroupMember" operation
        }else {
          #do "Add-AzureADGroupMember" operation
        }

    }
}
```

You can know more about the command(`Select-AzureADGroupIdsUserIsMemberOf`) wichi I used above in this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/select-azureadgroupidsuserismemberof?view=azureadps-2.0#examples).

Comment: Unfortunately I get an error

```
Select-AzureADGroupIdsUserIsMemberOf : Error occurred while executing SelectAzureADGroupIdsUserIsMemberOf 
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: One or more parameters of the function import 'checkMemberGroups' are missing from the request payload. The missing parameters are: groupIds. ```

Comment: Sry it's still not working. Now I get a different error... 

I'm using this function:
Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $groupids -RefObjectId $users

Add-AzureADGroupMember : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'RefObjectId'. Specified method is not supported.

Comment: Hi @thomsch I'm a little confused that why did you run the command `Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $groupids -RefObjectId $users`. The command in your question looks correct `Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $groupid -RefObjectId $user`.

Comment: @thomsch May I know if your problem was solved ? If still have problem, please let me know.

Comment: Unforunately the erorr persists:
`Add-AzureADGroupMember : Error occurred while executing AddGroupMember
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: One or more added object references already exist for the following modified properties: 'members'.`

Comment: @thomsch Could you please share the scripts which you are running now ?

Comment: I updated the code in my first post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @thomsch Sorry I wrote the operation backwards in my answer. We should "don't do add member operation" in the first condition of the "if" and "do the add member operation" in the "else". I have updated my answer, please have a try.